# variable from parameter @PUT in web service correct?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rs

Is this correct?

I want to get variable from @PUT method parameter in REST web service.

But I get the variable "Null" , how to get parameter?

Could anyone tell me?

```
@PUT
@Produces("application/html")
public Response postContainer(@PathParam("objecturi")String path){

    mongoDAOImpl impl=new mongoDAOImpl();
    Mongo mongo=impl.getConnection("127.0.0.1","27017");
    DB db=impl.getDataBase(mongo,"public");
    DBCollection coll=impl.getColl(db,"public");
    mongoDTO dto=new mongoDTO();
    dto.setParentpath("/home/public/liren");
    dto.setUserName("liren");
    dto.setPassWord("liren");
    dto.setFileName(path);
    dto.setAbsolutepath(dto.getParentpath()+"/"+dto.getFileName());

    boolean bool;
     try{
         file= new filemethods();
         bool=file.createcontainers(coll, dto, path);
         if(bool==true){
             return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();

         }else {
             return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_ACCEPTABLE).build();
         }
     }catch(Exception ex){
         return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).tag("Container create error"+ex.toString()).build();
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your method parameter an http parameter like /uri?objecturi=/some/path? Then you have to use @QueryParam("objecturi") instead of @PathParam("objecturi").

Answer (score 1):

What do you have in your `@Path` annotation?
Basically if you want your code to work, you must have something like `@Path("/url/{objecturi}")`

Answer (score 0):

For HTTP PUT-method you need to use form parameters with "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" MIME-type of your HTTP Header and @QueryParam annotation.

```
@PUT
@Produces("application/html")
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public Response postContainer(@QueryParam("objecturi")String path){
...
}
```

Hope this helps.